# Use mailApp to send email with images and other from

Tags: google-apps-script

I try this code and works well, it sends the email with the account I need:

```js
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
var Mailfrom = aliases[0];
GmailApp.sendEmail(
                    "email@gmail.com", 
                    "From an alias", 
                    "A message from an alias!", 
                    {
                      "from": Mailfrom
                    });
```

On the other hand I have a code that sends images: (Works well)

```js
var correo = "email@gmail.com";
var copia = "copymail@gmail.com"
var logo = DriveApp.getFileById(AxId).getBlob();
var fileID = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('IFILE');
var img = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob();
MailApp.sendEmail({
                    to: correo,
                    cc: copia,
                    subject: asunto,
                    htmlBody: cuerpo,
                    inlineImages: {
                      Axlogo: logo, 
                      Evidencia: img
                    }
                  });
```

What I want is to join both options, I try this:

```js
MailApp.sendEmail({
                     to: correo,
                     cc: copia, 
                     subject: asunto,
                     htmlBody: cuerpo,
                     inlineImages: {
                       Axlogo: logo,
                       Evidencia: img
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     'from': Mailfrom
                  });
```

Web console shows: `uncaught`

```js
MailApp.sendEmail({
                    to: correo,
                    cc: copia,
                    subject: asunto,
                    htmlBody: cuerpo,
                    inlineImages: {
                      Axlogo: logo, 
                      Evidencia: img
                    },
                    {
                      'from': Mailfrom
                    }
                  })
```

Programing window shows: `invalid property ID`

How should I write the options to send the mail with the "from" option and the option of the images `inlineImages`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You have to use `GmailApp` as opposed to `MailApp` if you wish to use aliases when sending emails. You also have to specify in the html body where you wish the inline images to be displayed, referring to the names specified in the `inlineImages` parameter.*

#### Code:

You can complete what you are wishing to do with the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var image = DriveApp.getFileById("<id-of-file>").getBlob().setName('name');
  var html =  '<body>' + 'Test <img src="cid:image">' + '</body>'
  GmailApp.sendEmail('toAddress@domain.com', 
                     'subject', 
                     'message body',
                     {
                       htmlBody: html,
                       inlineImages: {
                         'image': image
                       }
                       from: 'alias@mydomain.com'
                     });
}
```

Just remember to get the relevant alias to insert into `from`, and change the file ID, recipient address, and email information as you need.

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)
- [Google Apps Script - `File.getBlob()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getblob)

Comment: Thanks.
Yoy are right, what happens is that i was using two different functions and when validating in the google documentation, they don´t have the same parameters.